# updating CentOS 7.3.1611

Tags: centos, upgrade

Here is my dilema. I have a CentOS 7.3.1611 server. If I run yum check-update I can see that it would be update to CentOS 7.9 since see the baseurl or mirrorlist is configured to look at what $releasever is set to. $releasever is set to 7 and  the 7 directory is just a symlink to the whatever the latest is, which is 7.9 ATM. I know that CentOS is providing updates / security patches only for the last point in time release (that is 7.9 ATM) and a security scanner has reported diff vulnerabilities for the system hence the motivation to upgrade. The problem ? I don't know what can break when moving from 7.3 to 7.9 :) Should I go stepwise by disabling the default repos and adding a "custome" that would point to an archived point in time release such as 7.4.708, upgrade, check if all is ok, then adding    7.5.1804, updating / checking all up to 7.9.2009  ? Here's an example:

````
name=CentOS-7.4.1708 - Base
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/centos/7.4.1708/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7

[updates-7.4.1708]
name=CentOS-7.4.1708 - Updates
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/centos/7.4.1708/updates/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7


[extras-7.4.1708]
name=CentOS-7.4.1708 - Extras
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/centos/7.4.1708/updates/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7```


Or should I go straight for 7.9 ? 

Again, I'm worried about breaking stuff. Any recommendations folks ?
````

Answer (score 1):

I recommend upgrading to 7.9 and then keeping your system up-to-date. A great deal of effort goes into ensuring that updates within a major release *don’t* break things.

The safety of upgrades comes from two major ingredients. The first is that `yum` (and `rpm`) preserve the integrity of package dependencies: packages describe their dependencies in detail, and `yum` and `rpm` by default won’t allow package installations, removals, or upgrades if they would break other packages’ dependencies. (Removals can be cascaded, so removing a package will remove all the packages which would be broken by the removal, but that’s not an issue on upgrades generally speaking.) The second is [the RHEL 7 ABI compability guarantee](https://access.redhat.com/articles/rhel-abi-compatibility), which CentOS 7 also benefits from: there is a long list of libraries whose ABIs are guaranteed to be preserved throughout the lifetime of RHEL 7 and CentOS 7, across all upgrades in those releases. This means that even third-party applications, or applications built from source, will continue working if all their dependencies are covered by the ABI guarantee. (They may continue working even if they have other dependencies, but it would be up to you to check.)

If you’re really worried that something might break, clone your system either so that you can test the upgrade on the clone first, or have a backup you can revert to if necessary.

Comment: Thank you @Stephen Kitt. But would it make sense  to do stuff like review the yum `update output` to cross check what will be removed/updated etc?

Comment: Yes, always, even on small upgrades — at least check that the planned removals (if any) make sense.

Comment: @Thank you Stephen Kitt. But I'm still fail to understand how this dependency check can be done. I mean if say I run dovecot i can run `yum deplist dovecot` and it will print out the dependency + where it can be satisfied. But AFAIK when  I run `yum update` it will resolve (and perhaps install/update) dependencies for the packages to be updated if I'm not mistaken? So there's no telling if such an update will break another app that is relaying on say a shared library at version 1.2 but due to the upgrade performed with yum it was updated to 1.4. Is there a way to check it ? 1/2

Comment: But again with so many packages installed on a system I don't see how this could be done, taking into consideration that of course dependencies have then also their own dependencies and so on 2/2

Comment: `yum` does the dependency check for you. If all your applications are packaged, then the upgrades performed by `yum` should be safe; by default it will even prefer holding upgrades back instead of deleting packages. Problems can occur if you have a non-packaged application which relies on a library which isn’t covered by the ABI guarantee; but only you can know what non-packaged applications you have. Those are the only dependencies you’d need to check manually.

Comment: "yum does the dependency check for you." Ok so just to confirm that I understand. If I run `yum update` if there's anything to be updated (packages, shared library, whatever) becuase there's a new package version and dependencies have to change to, yum will check against the entire system and try to determine if any of the changes to be introduced can/will break stuff for software that is not going to be updated now when I run `yum update`? Could you please confirm ? 1/2

Comment: Also,could you please elaborate on " Problems can occur if you have a non-packaged application which relies on a library which isn’t covered by the ABI guarantee; but only you can know what non-packaged applications you have. Those are the only dependencies you’d need to check manually." Non-package application like if one would compile/install from source rather than the distro's repo? ABI guarantee ? Could you please provide a link where I could read further ?  2/2

Comment: See the updated answer.